# What is the adic realization of a Bernoulli shift ?

Tags: ergodic-theory

Roughly speaking, a theorem by Vershik says that every ergodic invertible measure-preserving transformation is isomorphic to some "adic" transformation on the spaces of paths of a Bratelli-Vershik graph. What is the adic transformation corresponding to a Bernoulli shift ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that nobody knows. The reason is that Vershik's proof uses Rokhlin's towers and is thus virtually non-constructive.

As far as I know, the only known examples of explicit adic realizations are substitutional dynamical systems and the irrational rotations of the circle. Even for a simple ergodic rotation of the 2-torus this is an open question, let alone Bernoulli shifts.

Comment: I believe I know a way to construct an adic realization of a rotation of the 2-torus. I can send you my notes about that if you are interested.

Comment: This has been done, I believe. A paper in Monatshefte a few years ago, don't remember the author.

Comment: More generally, I believe I know a way to construct an adic realization of $T \times S$ once one has an adic realization of $S$. But I'm not sure it works.

Comment: Well, good luck. I look forward to reading about this one day.

Comment: I try to explain this construction on an example [here](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/temp/AdicProduct_v00.pdf). Another example [here](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/temp/OPgraph.pdf). I discovered this construction while I was working on [something else](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/temp/ScalePaper_v04.pdf) (currently I do not intend to publish this work).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can realize the Bernoulli shift on $k$ symbols as an adic transformation on the following Bratelli-Vershik diagram: put $k$ nodes on the first level. Suppose levels 1 to $n$ have been defined, and call $L_n$ the set of nodes in the $n$-th level. Then nodes on the $(n+1)$-th level are pairs $(i,j)\in L_n\times L_n$, where $(i,j)$ is connected to $i$ and to $j$ (in this order) to the $n$-th level. Does not this work?

Comment: Thanks to both of you.
@Thierry, hence the graph is "homogeneous", in the sense that the number of paths to some node at level $n$ to a node at level $1$ is the same for all nodes at level $n$ ? 

Comment: In fact I am not very easy with the adic representation. Is it easy to check that Thierry's proposal is fine ?

Comment: Indeed, the graph I proposed is homogeneous: Each node of level n has exactly k^n paths to the root of the diagram. But then I must admit that this poses some problem, since this introduces eigenvalues for the associated adic transformation. So this adic transformation is rather an extension of the Bernoulli shift (probably a direct product with an odometer).  
